# Generate an ECDSA key and CSR with OpenSSL

Tags: dsa, openssl, certificate

I know how to generate an RSA Private Key and CSR:

```
openssl genrsa -out my.key.pem 2048
openssl req -new -sha256 -key my.key.pem -out my.csr
```

But, how do I do the same with an ECDSA (Elliptic Curve Digital Signature Algorithm)?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

For a list of possible curve names, run:

```
openssl ecparam -list_curves
```

Then, pick a curve from the list and replace your first line with:

```
openssl ecparam -name secp521r1 -genkey -noout -out my.key.pem
```

(replace `secp521r1` with whichever curve you choose from the list)

Finally, generate the CSR as you have done:

```
openssl req -new -sha256 -key my.key.pem -out my.csr
```

Comment: If he/she wants to use it in a TLS server, then they will also need to use a named curve, and *not* domain parameters. That means `ecparam` and `-param_enc named_curve` will need to be used. Also see [Elliptic Curve Cryptography | Named Curves](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Elliptic_Curve_Cryptography#Named_Curves) on the OpenSSL wiki.

Comment: @jww `-param_enc named_curve` appears to be the default, at least with newer version of OpenSSL. Thus leaving it out should be OK.

Comment: Private keys should be password protected.

Comment: `openssl ecparam -genkey -name secp521r1 | openssl ec -aes256 -out my.key.pem`

Answer (score 0):

Based on the accepted answer, I'd like to use `genpkey` command for more general usage:

```
openssl genpkey -algorithm EC -pkeyopt ec_paramgen_curve:secp521r1 -out my.key.pem
```

> `-algorithm`, `-pkeyopt` can be referred to [openssl man](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.1/man1/openssl-genpkey.html) and [KEY GENERATION OPTIONS](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.1/man1/openssl-genpkey.html#KEY-GENERATION-OPTIONS)

Then:

```
openssl req -new -sha256 -key my.key.pem -out my.csr
```